# Detecting duplicate music files

Tags: mp3

I've got two directories containing ~20 GB of music files (mostly mp3, some ogg), and I would like to detect all duplicate songs. There are two complicating factors:

1. A song may have different filenames in the two directories.
2. Two files containing the same song may have different ID3 tags and thus have different checksums.

What is a good approach to solving this?

Comment: This is identical to a Ron Jeffries/Chet Hendriksen workshop question!  Do you really have the problem or are you trying to finish the workshop code?

Comment: I really have the problem. I imported all my music into iTunes, so now I have my old music directory and my iTunes directory. Basically I want to know which files from my old music directory has not made it into iTunes...

Comment: Why not send Ron or Chet a note and ask how they solved it?  As I remember, my solution had something to do with name formats.  http://www.xprogramming.com/ or http://www.hendricksonxp.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I have gone about this in the past is to use genpuids that come from Music IP. The closed source software creates an audio fingerprint of a file regardless of format, id3, checksum etc.

More information can be found [here](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/genpuid).

This should ensure the most amount of positive duplicate matches and minimize false positives. It can also correctly tag incorrect id3 tags.

Comment: This looks like a great idea, but it appears that there are a bunch of AAC-files in there as well, which genpuid does not support (on Linux, at least).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do (or have done before)...

1. Load all songs onto itunes (bear with me)
   (note, if you can use itunes here, then stop ... I assume your list of dupes is long and unmanageable)
2. Delete all songs, sending them to the trash can, this way you get rid of the directory structure
3. Obviously, don't "empty trash". Rescue the songs to a folder on your desktop
4. Use software like [mediamonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/), [dupe eliminato](http://www.bestshareware.net/download/dupe-eliminator-for-itunes.htm)r or even [itunes](http://apple.com/itunes) itself to identify the duplicates. Dupe eliminator is good in that it checks by a varying amount of factors, artist, length, filesize and whatnot and guesses what is a dupe and what isn't)
5. Reload onto Itunes, this time around check "Auto arrange songs", which will drop your new, dupeless list onto a nice by-artist-by-album arrangement

... voila! (or if you read digg: "...profit!")

/mp

Answer (score 1):

Are the ID3/OGG-equiv artist and song metatags accurate? If they are, you could use those.

Edit: If they're not, perhaps they could be made to be... If you're only dealing with whole albums, there are several tools that will get all the tag data based on the number of tracks and their lengths.

If you're dealing with mixes of albums and single files, it gets more complicated.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't think I can rely on them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a library that can parse the files, you can run the hash on the audio data. This will not help you if the song is a different rip or has be recompressed/transcoded/etc.

Comment: It would be a bit beastly on the processing front... Just getting lots of ID3s takes an age but hashing audio data on top? Eeek!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's more elegant solutions out there - but if the audio data is equivalent, then stripping the ID3 tags and hashing should do the trick. After hashing, you can put the ID3 tags back if you like.

Comment: I'd just extract and hash the audio data stream in isolation from the rest of the data in the file (ID3 tag, etc.), without actually modifying any files.  I'm sure there's software to strip ID3 info, but adding it back later would require more complex software to remember what's been removed from where, or an online service could be used to scan and identify the audio in the file so song info could be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Last.fm API](http://www.last.fm/api/show?service=356) would be useful. It includes a track.getInfo call which returns XML including the track's length, artist name, track number, etc. You could compare tracks and see if they have more than N fields equal and if so, assume they're the same track.

I have no idea about whether they're going to be OK with you submitting API requests for 40gb of music, though.

Comment: The API is based on having semi-correct data in the first place... And, yeah, I think they'd ban your IP within the first 100 rapid-fire requests.. Nice idea though..

Comment: I actually wrote a utility that uses the Last.fm API and it included a way to limit requests and cache data received.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: find a library to get the mp3's length as well as a pointer to the audio data (looks like there are a couple libraries out there that can do this), do a first pass filter based on song lengths, and for the songs that have matching lengths checksum their audio data. Similar to this [script for finding duplicate files / images](http://parand.com/say/index.php/2008/10/15/python-script-for-finding-and-removing-duplicate-files/).

Answer (score 0):

Some adaptation of [ffTES](https://github.com/monfort/ffTES) has worked great for me for a very similar task.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem, so I wrote a command-line program that tries to detect similar audio files by comparing acoustic fingerprints: https://codeberg.org/derat/soundalike

It uses the `fpcalc` utility from [Chromaprint](https://github.com/acoustid/chromaprint) to generate the fingerprints, and then builds a lookup table to find possible matches before comparing fingerprints more rigorously.

It worked pretty well when I ran against my music library, but there are various flags to tune its behavior if needed. If it works for you (or if it doesn't), let me know!